# slow search on postgres table despite index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

the following search is taking 15 seconds despite an index on the last_time column which is a timestamp

```
select * from my_table where last_time>now() - interval '1 hour'
```

The table has around 15 M rows and the query returns around 100 rows.
I have recreated the index and have vacuumed the table. but the search is still slow.
Similar searches on similar tables of comparable size return around 1000 rows in < 1 sec.

```
Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..625486.61 rows=3817878 width=237) (actual time=16397.053..16397.054 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: (last_time > (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 11453235
  Buffers: shared hit=73 read=424975
Planning Time: 0.290 ms
Execution Time: 16397.097 ms
```

Any suggests?

Comment: What if you hoist out `now() - interval '1 hour'` into a variable and compare against that? I'd expect any half-decent optimiser to do that for you anyway, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: Sorry just read your comment in detail will do.

Comment: The planner expects nearly 4 million rows to be returned, but then the condition does remove all rows from the result (yielding an empty result). This is very often a sign of outdated statistics. Does `vacuum analyze my_table;` change anything?

Comment: Bingo! Following vacuum analyze:Index Scan using idx_rfg_elh_lastutcts on my_table  (cost=0.44..5.60 rows=1 width=237) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (last_time > (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))
  Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 14.293 ms
Execution Time: 0.088 ms

Comment: Could be a very old version of PostgreSQL.